# How to save/cache all data on device for quick loading and updates in background when React native app launches?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using axios for API calls, and Async storage for storing some details like user profile and all. But Async storage seems very slow.

My apps' key functionality needs internet to work, but lot of screens would have content which doesn't update in realtime or always. How do I save all that info in local so whenever new session of the app is launched, the screens show fully loaded instead of querying data from API and showing a loader, the info update can happen in the background. Like how all the major apps work is by not loading already loaded content but somehow saving it on the device itself, but at the same time allowing for updating if new info comes in.

Some sort of DB in the app to store all info would work? if yes, what's the best to go with Redux, Axios implementation that is fast and not as slow as Async Storage?

Comment: for me async storage works pretty well,
I usually make a loading screen, where I preload redux store and them move to the main app,

Answer (score 0):

Async storage should work fine. To implement this, you will need to make sure to use the API data only on the first app start, and not subsequent starts. Then add an updater function that checks for updates. Here's a rough implementation.

1. When App loads, try to get your data from the local storage. If it's the first start, there's nothing in the storage, so fetch the data from API.
2. Once data comes back. Save it to the local storage for next app start. Display the data.
3. If the data exists in local storage (subsequent starts), you will need to send a API call to fetch the latest data. Once the data comes back, put it in the local storage. Make sure this is not a blocking call. It's up to you if you want to update the current data on screen.

Comment: So, there is no need of DB implementation and Async storage does the job by just increasing it's size limits?

Comment: looks like there's a 6MB limit on Android, unlimited in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on several projects using the redux-persist library. In short, what it does is cache the information you handle with redux, without having to worry about saving information with Async storage.

If you really don't want to use Async storage and you already use Redux, I think it's the perfect option. I have been with this library for about 2 years and so far I have not had any problems.

For more information visit:
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist